# How do I changed the language used by the Gnome spell checker?

Tags: locale

I'm a Canadian, but often get American spelling suggestions from the spell checker in Ubuntu.  How do I switch to a Canadian dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Marco Ceppi is right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3227/how-do-i-changed-the-language-used-by-the-gnome-spell-checker/3234#3234) about this being based on the locale, but the easiest way to change this is through System -> Administration -> Language Support in the graphical user-interface (it will also make sure all the right packages are installed, etc.).

Comment: Does that mean that the default dictionary for spell check must be the same as the language for the menus and messages?

Answer (score 4):

The spell checker is based on your Locale - if you switch it to en_CA (or en_GB if en_CA is not available) you should be more Canadian like spellings.

Get a list of installed languages with the following:

`locale -a`

You can view your current selected locale with:

`locale`

Once you've selected the one which best suites you - you can update it here:

`sudoedit /etc/default/locale`

Be aware if an entry from `locale -a` ends with `.utf8` it needs to be entered as `.UTF-8` in the default locale.

After you make those changes you'll need to reboot for them to apply.